# How to map a joined-subclass with a composite key

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to map `Operationfinancial` as joined-subclasses of `Operation`. The difference in this model from the examples I've found is that both are using a composite key.

Operation Map.

```
public class OperationMap : ClassMapping<Operation>
    {
       public OperationMap()
         {
            this.Table("ECM_OPE_Operation");

            this.ComponentAsId(
           x => x.Id, compAsId =>
           {
               compAsId.Property(x => x.Id, m => { m.Column("Id");  m.NotNullable(true); });
               compAsId.Property(x => x.EventId, m => { m.Column("EventId"); m.NotNullable(true); });
           });

            this.Property(x => x.CreatedOn, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        }
   }
```

OperationFinancial Map.

```
 public class OperationfinancialMap : JoinedSubclassMapping<OperationFinancial>, IEntityMap
   {
        public OperationfinancialMap()
         {
        this.Table("ECM_OFI_OperationFinancial");
        this.Key(m =>
            {
                m.Column("Id");
                m.Column("EventId");
            });
        this.Property(x => x.Quantity, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        this.Property(x => x.Amount);
    }
   }
```

But when i run i've got this error

*Foreign key (FK3EDDC7CF4D8FE893:ECM_OFI_OperationFinancial [EventId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ECM_OPE_Operation [Id, EventId])*

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
 Key(key => key.Columns(c => c.Name("Id"), c => c.Name("EventId")));
```